# Is it possible to manage sessions duration with IdentityPlatform/FirebaseAuth custom tokens?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm working on a project that has the following requirement: **Sessions should never last more than 90 days.**

I'm also using Firestore, and by extension to authenticate users, Firebase Auth. I want to give access to Firestore to my android and ios clients, **for 90 days maximum**. After that duration the session should automatically expire.

I initially thought custom tokens were the solution, because I thought they were just a different term for ID tokens. But in reality they can be used to get a refresh token that never expires.

I therefore thought about managing the refresh tokens myself, by:

- issuing my own refresh tokens
- verifying their validity
- creating a new custom token
- exchange the custom token with an id token and refresh token on the back end
- only return the ID token to the client
- the client would give it to firestore.

I don't mind managing expiration and renewing the id token myself on the my back end.

Now my problem is that when I look at the official SDKs for firestore on Android and SDKs, none seem to allow for **just attaching an id token** to requests?

Is there a solution to my issue? Or maybe even a better approach?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to forbid users from signing in directly and instead provided them with Custom Tokens from my backend.

I added a custom claim on that token that was a custom expiration date, and in the Firestore access rules, I check if that expiration date is passed or not like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if false;
  }

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.token.customExpirationTimeInMillis > request.time.toMillis()
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```